# Determine the motherboard/chipset type on FreeBSD box

Tags: freebsd, hardware

I need to know what chipset / motherboard type for a FreeBSD box. 
Is there a quick way to do that without ports ?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`pciconf -lv` will give a list of the PCI devices in the system. It's not a great way to read chipset information and may return very little usable information, at any rate it will be in cryptic form. The `dmidecode` port would be much preferred, but `pciconf` is part of the base OS.

Comment: I don't see it installed on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Ubuntu is Linux, this question is about FreeBSD, a completely different operating system.

Answer (score 11):

[dmidecode](http://www.nongnu.org/dmidecode/) should do the trick. actually all the tricks :)

Comment: You will find dmidecode in /usr/ports/sysutils/dmidecode